# how to set window's title according to a file i choose in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have a scroll menu contain files names. When I click on a file name in the menu, I want to create a window has the file name as a title.

In the code below I can create the window but without a title.

The problem is in the line ( title: jsonobj[ii], // I got undefined here ).

```
var scrollMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu');
var files = Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: 'php/getfiles.php',
  success: function(response, opts) {
    var jsonobj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    for(var ii = 0; ii < jsonobj.length; ii++){
      scrollMenu.add({
        text: jsonobj[ii], // working good
        handler: function () {
          var winfile = Ext.create('widget.window', {
            region: 'center',
            height: 500,
            width: 900,
            x: 500,
            y: 100,
            title: jsonobj[ii], // not working
            closable: true,
            plain: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            preventBodyReset: true,
          });
          winfile.show();
        }
      });
    }
  },
  failure: function(response, opts) {
    console.log('somthing went wrong with this AJAX call' + response.status);
  }
});
```

Comment: `preventBodyReset: true,` will throw an error in some browsers (comma after last property in the hash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all `handler` callbacks are defined in the same closure. That means that once `ii` is changed in scope of `success` callback - it automatically affects all `handler` callbacks. Since `jsonobj[jsonobj.length] === undefined` you always get undefined title. You should wrap `handler` with some other closure like below:

```
handler: (function(){
    var title = jsonobj[ii];
    return function () {
        var winfile = Ext.create('widget.window', {
            region: 'center',
            height: 500,
            width: 900,
            x: 500,
            y: 100,
            title: title,
            closable: true,
            plain: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            preventBodyReset: true
        });
        winfile.show();
    }
}())
```

Comment: I just have another question please. When i am using the code above, i got the file title and its content correctly in the window but another problem has been appeared. Now when i am choosing a file i can see it in the window but when i choose another one new blank window get opened and the content of the first window changed according to the file I have been chosen.
My question is How to open a new window with the corresponding file content i have chosen?
Thanks

Comment: From the example it is not clear how you fill the content of the window, there is no `items` or `html` property you set in the initial configuration. However, once I had the similar issue and it was because my windows had the same `id`. Check that your windows have different `id`s, if it does not help please update the example with the way you fill the content of a windows.

Comment: thanks for your replying Vadim. i just added the following code:
autoLoad: {
   url: 'index.html',
   scripts: true,
    callback: function (el, succ, resp, opts) {  getSelectedFile(title); }
                          }

it did what i want but always in the same window other new windows still empty